# excellent setjmp/longjmp tutorials

Tags: c, setjmp

Hi I'd like to read good tutorials on setjmp/longjmp in C. It'd be better if there're examples which are real rather than artificial.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Wikipedia's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longjmp is quiet good. I just learned about this topic now.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a tutorial as such, but the [libpng documentation](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) describes how the library uses setjmp/longjmp to do error handling.

Answer (score 1):

The book "C interfaces and implementation" explains the concept well and implements a usable "exception" simulation in C using these constructs. The code for it (chapter 4) is freely available [online here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/toc.html).

Edit: also see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692814/exception-handling-in-c-what-is-the-use-of-setjmp-returning-0)

Answer (score 0):

Then you should read [Advanced Programming in the UNIX(R) Environment (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433079)  Here's the sample you're looking for http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0201433079/ch10lev1sec15 (just a preview)