# My exit(status) with setjmp un longjmp

Tags: c, exit, setjmp

Problem is - I have to implement my own exit(status) with setjmp and longjmp. Maybe someone could give some pointers?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have tried nothing since only implementation that is allowed is with setjmp/longjmp and I really cant imagine how to create solution from these functions. Well what I have done is, I searched for exit implementation in kernel source, but there was a lot of stuff which probably does the same thing but with different methods. (More precisely I was looking at _exit())

Comment: You might like to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1733649/694576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I think of right now, is to call `setjmp` early in `main`, and then create a `MyExit` function which does a `longjmp` to the `setjmp` in `main` and does a `return` with some value (provided from the `longjmp` call).

Comment: This looks like a valid solution, I didn`t notice, that I can put macros in main function. Probably that is the place where I can put setjmp and control return in case of jumping back. Thank you.

Comment: What macros are you talking about?

Comment: I know what macros are, I just don't see what it has to do with this question or answer. `setjmp()` is a function (or it can be treated as if it is).

Comment: @Barmar If you put macros in beginning of main (which contains setjmp and other constructions) you can return to the beginning with myExit and return nonzero code returned by setjmp. The thing is, in beginning I thought that I have to do this without macros.