# Writing my own longjmperror() in C

Tags: c, setjmp

I was looking at the manual for longjmp and in the Errors part it says this:

> ERRORS
>
> If the contents of the env are corrupted, or correspond to an environment that has already returned, the longjmp() routine calls the routine longjmperror(3).  If longjmperror()
>        returns, the program is aborted (see abort(3)).  The default version of longjmperror() prints the message ``longjmp botch'' to standard error and returns.  **User programs wishing to exit more gracefully should write their own versions of longjmperror().**

How would i write my own version of longjmperror? From what i know in C you can't override functions and i really need the long jump to exit in a specific way when it doesn't find the point to jump to.

Comment: You need to write the function, of course, and then you need to tell the linker to use it instead of the library function. The details of doing this will differ by platform.

Comment: Clearly you haven't actually tried it.  Do try it before you convince us that it cannot work.

Comment: Maybe you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733649/excellent-setjmp-longjmp-tutorials

Comment: I looked. There are no tutorials that teach you how to treat errors and google search returned 169 unrelated search results for longjmperror

Comment: The man page is saying that your implementation of `longjmperror()` shouldn't return if a more graceful exit than aborting is desired. So it should call `exit()` or `_exit()` instead of returning (for example).

Comment: I understand that. But long jump is a library function and i assume longjmperror is in the same library, so when i try to compile it will probably say longjmperror is a dublicated symbol. What i want to know is how to tell longjmp to use my longjmperror instead of the default one. There IS a default one. "The default version of longjmperror() prints the message ``longjmp botch'' to standard error and returns."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X (10.9.2, Mavericks) at any rate, the prototype for `longjmperror()` is:

```
void longjmperror(void);
```

You write a function with that signature.  It must not return (or, rather, if it does, the program will be `abort()`ed).  What you do in that function is your business, but bear in mind that things have gone moderately catastrophically wrong for the function to be called at all).  It might log an error to your log file, or just write a more meaningful message before exiting (instead of aborting and perhaps core dumping).

You link the object file containing the function ahead of the system library.  You are normally not expected to replace system functions, but this is one you are intended to override.

Comment: So the function has no implementation, just the signature?

Comment: I expect that the default implementation is `void longjmperror(void) { }`, or maybe there is an `fprintf(stderr, …)` inside the function.  Yes, there's just the signature specified; the rest is up to you.